# Not able to launch spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am not able to get this resolved. I have installed hadoop, and it works fine. And the hadoop paths are proper.

However, when I try to launch spark, I am a getting the following error

```
    /usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$ spark-shell
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$.org$apache$spark$internal$Logging$$isLog4j12(Logging.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.initializeLogIfNecessary(SparkSubmit.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

I have searched for various alternatives, and tried, but error remains the same.

This is my `~/.bashrc` file.

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161
export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin
export HIVE_CONF=/usr/local/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin/conf
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin/lib/*:.
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export SPARK_CONF=/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/lib/*:.
```

Also, the `sudo update-alternative --config java` and `sudo update-alternative --config javac

```
    There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java               0         manual mode
```

Another issue, which I have found out is that `java's` location is still `/usr/bin/java` and not the export path which I have set.

Please let me know, how to get over this.

Answer (score 0):

> Open {SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-env.sh

add following entry in the spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```

restart spark

This should resolve the issue. basically adding hadoop classpath to spark.

Answer (score 0):

I had the java location issue and the `NoClassDefFoundError` as well.

To overcome the java location issue, first I found available java installations by:

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Then I pointed `JAVA_HOME` to the java installation I need, for spark, it's typicaly like

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version_string>`
```

The version string needs to match one of the available java installations. For example `1.8.351`

Now try `java -version` again, it should be updated to the version you just set.

To understand what caused the `NoClassDefFoundError`, I tried
`SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=true spark-shell`
which printed out debugging info.

For me, I found the `NoClassDefFoundError` is caused by incorrect configuration in `{SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-env.sh`.

This is what worked for me in the `spark-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_HOME="<location_of_hadoop>"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop"
export SPARK_LOG_DIR="/var/log/spark"
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$($HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath):"$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"
```